# Memory leaks with QMenu

Tags: c++, qt, memory, valgrind

I tried creating a [Qt application](https://github.com/dipakgmx/Metronome). On using Valgrind, I see there are memory leaks caused by `QMenu`. Am not able to figure this out exactly. I did try following the [QT example for QTMenu class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-menus-example.html), but even this resulted in leaks. Valgrind notifies that the leaks happen here at the addMenu call:

```
void MainWindow::createMenu()
{
    //Create menus
    QAction *quit = new QAction("&Quit", this);
    QMenu *file = menuBar()->addMenu("&File");
    file->addAction(quit);
    connect(quit, &QAction::triggered,
    [=]() {
        QApplication::quit();
    });

    //Creating instances of ticker and timer here
    //Done so that the connection between ticker and timer is possible
    ticker = new Ticker(this);
    timer = new Timer(this);
    connect(timer, &Timer::timeout, ticker, &Ticker::playSound);
}
```

This happens to be the Valgrind log

```
The leaks happen with 78 (32 direct, 46 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 11,297 of 16,371
  in MainWindow::createMenu() in /home/user/Documents/C/QT/Metronome/MainWindow.cpp:47
  1: operator new(unsigned long) in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
  2: 0x1630a434
  3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.5.1
  4: QMainWindow::menuBar() const in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.5.1
  5: MainWindow::createMenu() in /home/user/Documents/C/QT/Metronome/MainWindow.cpp:47
  6: MainWindow::setMainWindow() in /home/user/Documents/C/QT/Metronome/MainWindow.cpp:20
  7: MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*) in /home/user/Documents/C/QT/Metronome/MainWindow.cpp:6
  8: main in /home/user/Documents/C/QT/Metronome/main.cpp:22
```

So my question is, how do I go about laying out the Menu to avoid memory leaks? Incidentally, deleting the `QAction`, `QMenu` section results in no leaks.

Comment: Have your newed your main window?

Comment: Make sure to create your main window on the stack or delete it at the end of main(), otherwise valgrind will report leaks. Also, which platform are you testing on?

Comment: Am testing it on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Let me try making the MainWindow on the stack and then see the response.

Comment: Well, that did the trick!    Did a `MainWindow *window = new MainWindow();` and now I see no leaks

Comment: No related to your problem, just a note on your code, you can write that connect as `connect(quit, &QAction::triggered, qApp, &QApplication::quit);`